# Different subnet with the same gateway

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, ip, subnet, gateway

I have a virtual machine with a static IP (I can't login to change it) with a different subnet compared to my entire network and I need to communicate with it. In particular, this is my setup:

- Gateway (192.168.1.1)
- Kali Linux (192.168.1.14)
- Windows (192.168.1.254)
- Virtual Machine (192.168.110.151)

The VM is running with Virtual Box on Windows machine while Kali is on my laptop. Both Windows and Kali are connected via ethernet to the router (192.168.1.1).

Is there a way to communicate from Kali to the VM with two different subnets?

Comment: Is your VM on bridged to the physical network? Does it have to access the Internet?

Comment: I used host-only interface, but I can't check if it has Internet connection because I don't have login credentials

Comment: I’m not asking if it *has* Internet access (it doesn’t), but whether it *wants* Internet access. :D Without bridging the VM, you won’t be able to access it from other machines.

Comment: Ok, so I will use a bridge connection and I will retry to add the secondary IP

Comment: Now I am able to ping 192.168.110.151 but if I try to scan the open services with nmap there is only rpcbind while I should see a port 80 open

Comment: Nice to see communications are up! I guess the VM isn’t working then. ;)

Comment: It works at 100%, I don't know where is the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign your Kali laptop a secondary IP address in the 192.168.110.x range with ifconfig:

```
ifconfig [nic]:0 [IP-Address] netmask [mask] up
```

Make it permanent by modifying `/etc/network/interfaces` add adding an `iface [nic]:0 inet static` stanza which contains the address and mask you require.

Comment: I used this command: `sudo ifconfig eth0:0 192.168.110.2 netmask 255.255.255.255 up`, but I can't ping the VM

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you made the firewall/router's inside interface 192.168.1.17 and 192.168.110.151 with a subnet mask of 255.252.0.0, it would be able to talk to both subnets without a problem.

additionally, I would probably be more a proponent of getting an additional interface for the router/firewall.